# Travelling in the Schengen Zone

Tags: schengen, airlines, check-in

My port of entry will be Spain after which I will travel to Amsterdam via KLM, Brussels by train, Paris by train and Rome via Alitalia.

My question if the check-in staff, in KLM and Alitalia counters, would ask me for a return ticket in the same way airlines ask when we commence an international trip as they should follow TIMATIC database, however, I am not sure about that for travelling in the Schengen Zone.

Thank you.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What is your question?

Comment: Are you planning to stay in Rome?

Comment: @phoog No I am leaving Schengen either from Rome or Madrid, still not decided about port of exit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason airlines sometimes ask for return tickets before they issue a boarding pass is that some countries require proof of return or onward travel as a condition of admitting certain travelers.  Those travelers won't make it through the passport check on arrival if they don't have the necessary ticket.

Worse, if the airline brings such a traveler to the destination country without that proof, the airline will usually be liable for a fine that can be as much as several thousand dollars/euros/pounds.

None of this applies to intra-Schengen travel.  There is no immigration check on arrival, and the airline is not required to enforce immigration law.

Some airlines in the low-cost sector are notorious for doing so anyway, but there does not appear to be any risk of a fine to the airline if they don't; rather, it appears to be another revenue stream.  Alitalia and KLM are not among the airlines that do this.

(A [previous version](https://travel.stackexchange.com/revisions/139414/1) of this answer addressed the arrival in Spain.)

Comment: @HenningMakholm I did not mean to imply that they would be made during the intra-Schengen travel.  I misread the question, and I was referring to the immigration check in Spain.  Thanks for bringing it to my attention.  I will either edit or delete this answer.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, very helpful

Answer (score 2):

I think you are overthinking. You are doing a very common type of travel.

You need a ticket which bring you outside Schengen. It is not important from where. Is is very common to arrive on a airport and depart to an other, either for business and for travel. (medium and long travels. Daily travels inside Schengen, or to/from e.g. UK or nearby countries are different).

In any case the officers could ask you for your travel plan (you do no need all documents, but having solid ideas), so it makes plausible you depart from an other airport.